# Adding an aliasName for url name app django

Tags: django, django-urls

In a django project, I have an app : app_signup.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app_signup',
```

**app_signup/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Is it possible to add an alias to the app in order to see the alias (http://localhost:8000/alias/) instead of the name of the app(http://localhost:8000/app_signup/) in the url on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` doesn't really matter. Your project's main `urls.py` file is the one that specifies the path. There when constructing the `urlpatterns` list, you can do `path('alias/', include('app_signup.urls'))` instead of `path('app_signup/', include('app_signup.urls'))`.

Comment: Thank you @shriakhilc, but it does not work.

Comment: @QDex Do you get any error? Can you add the current urls.py you are using to the question? Because this is working for me in a project

Comment: This is the urls.py of the project ```from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('home.urls')),
    path('contact/', include(contact.urls')),
    path('signup/', include('app_signup.urls')),
] ```

Comment: Hey, I've tested this by creating a new project and it works for me. Can you also include the `urls.py` that's inside your app_signup folder? It's possible you have something hard-coded there. Please edit the question, don't post it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from the example you added, you are editing the urls.py file within the app you created. Not your app, but directly in the project file (in the same directory as settings.py), urls.py probably as `path('app_signup/', include('app_signup.urls'))` as mentioned in the answer above. This is the urls.py you need to edit.